# Weblogic stop script

Tags: weblogic12c

I want to stop the WebLogic managed server without giving admin URL and username and password while executing ./stopmanagedweblogic.sh Is there any way to create as stop script in which we can define admin URL and username and password and while stopping we have to just execute : ./stopmanagedweblogic.sh managed server name.

Comment: A good solution is to use a WLST script (as the stopWebLogic.sh) but with a secured userid and password. First, use the storeuserconfig() WLST function to create a user configuration including encrypted username and password. Now, connect to your server providing this secured configuration instead of your clear login and password (see the WLST connect() function. At last, call the shutdown() WLST function to stop your server. Read this [wlst documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/config_scripting/reference.html#wp1049091) for details.